# How to make absolutely positioned popups on top of tables with independent scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, css-position

I have two columns, both scrolled in y-axis independently, depending on the content height.
Each column contain boxes. So far that is working fine.

Problem comes when I want to add popup boxes when the user clicks on one of the existing boxes. I want to make these boxes:

1. Remain positioned absolutely to the clicked div position
2. Be visible on top of the columns (currently they are being covered by adjacent column and horizontal scrollbar appears)

So what I'm trying to achieve is:

[image: required result]

And what I currently have is [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/d2nfh5ak/)

`z-index` obviously isn't helping.

Is there a quick simple css-only fix to it, or fairly simple jQuery hack?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying an element outside overflow hidden container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301400/displaying-an-element-outside-overflow-hidden-container)

Comment: I would put one popup div inside your `main` div instead of your two column divs.

Comment: But than if you scroll the column down it'll behave as `position:fixed`: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2nfh5ak/1/)

Comment: Mr_Green - thanks for the link, indeed that was similar issue and after mulling it over I managed to get it to work.