# How to achieve that only one nested element should overflow it's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the multiple-select jquery plugin for an select element. The outer div (containing the multiple-select box) has a max-height. If I open the multiple-select box it is cut-off and I have to scroll down to see all options:

```js
$('select').multipleSelect();
```

```css
#outer {
  max-height: 110px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
#select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <p>
    Below you find a multiple select box that should overflow the outer div.
  </p>
  <label for="select">Multiple select:</label>
  <select id="select">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>
  <p>
    Scroll to the button when the select box is open.
  </p>
  <button>
    Do nothing
  </button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mdxuz1w/)

If I open the multiple-select box all options should be visible. So the options should be overflow the outer div. How can I achieve this?

If I set the position of `div.ms-parent` to `fixed` I'm getting the desired behavior until I'm scrolling down, because the select box is fixed and not moving with the other content.

Using the `z-index` also not working in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying an element outside overflow hidden container](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24301400/1577396)

Comment: @marco235 i edited my answer with a better solution. check it out. maybe it will help you better. thanks for accepting my answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made a kind of oldschool solution with JQ ( as i am not very familiar with multipleselect() plugin )

see here > **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mdxuz1w/6/)**

code :

```
$('select').multipleSelect();
var sTop = $('.ms-parent ').offset().top,
sHeight = $('.ms-parent ').height()
$('.ms-drop.bottom').css('top',sTop+sHeight)
```

CSS

```
.ms-drop {
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
}
```

for the `.ms-drop` to get out of it's container you need to set `position:fixed` to it. and then with JQ i calculated it's `top` position by finding the `offset().top` of the `.ms-parent` and it's height. these 2 combined gives the `top` position of your `.ms-drop`

hope it helps.

**EDIT: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mdxuz1w/20/)**

if you want the `ms-drop` to stay in the same position and not scroll down when you scroll inside the green div ( `#outer`) you should add a scroll function where you calculate the scroll distance and deduct it from the `top` position of the `ms-drop` so it will always stay in that position

so you will have the following JQ :

```
$('select').multipleSelect();
var sTop = $('.ms-parent ').offset().top,
    sHeight = $('.ms-parent ').height()

$('.ms-drop.bottom').css('top',sTop+sHeight)
$("#outer").on("scroll",function(){
    var oScroll = $(this).scrollTop()
    $('.ms-drop.bottom').css('top',sTop+sHeight-oScroll)

})
```

Comment: I do a little change regarding the start position if the page/div was scrolled. Here is my final solution https://jsfiddle.net/8mdxuz1w/21/

Comment: @marco235 well i thought you wanted the `ms-drop` to stay in the same position when you scroll ...... directly under the `.ms-parent ` that's why i made that edit on scroll

Answer (score 3):

The `container` option on this plugin achieves that. Try initiating the plugin like this:

```
$('select').multipleSelect({
   container: "body",
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8mdxuz1w/1/

Then, you'll need to limit the width of the dropdown.